# Rigging questions - How do I make the drum of this revolver rotate only from the center of a barrel/barrel to frame question

Tags: rigging, bones, parent

I was wondering how I would make the drum of a revolver barrel rotate in a centered position so it can only spin and not actually change position if that makes sense.

My second question would be, as of right now if you rotate the barrel of the revolver -- it would fold into itself like so.Essentially, if you try to rotate the barrel it won't move on the right point, ie the little circular shape and fold into itself.

How could I make it so the revolver barrel rotates along the proper point in regards to the frame? ie that little circular point where the weapon root bone is.

Thank you so much for reading, and here is the blend file. https://a.pomf.cat/wkyqgw.blend

I would provide the pics but I don't have the rep.

edit: First issue resolved by lemon, still need help on the second!

Comment: what is the "little circular shape" and what do you mean by "fold into itself" ?

Comment: Basically instead of the first result: http://puu.sh/pvKnN/178c635851.png
I need this to happen: http://puu.sh/pvMbs/2a8fabaa9f.png

Answer (score 2):

As the barrel is symetric, you can find its center in edit mode by selecting all the vertices and use <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (snap), then choose "Cursor to selected".

[image]

Now back to object mode. You can add a single bone armature and it will be created at the 3D cursor position (so it is centered to the barrel). Simply edit it (if you want as it is not mandatory here) in order to align the bone tail along the barrel (but keep the bone head in place along the same Y axis).

The barrel will rotate around the bone.
[image]

Edit (considering the comments) :

You can parent the bone placed above with the "barrel" (?) bone in blue below.
Go to pose mode for the "barrel" bone. Select the previous bone then select the "barrel" bone and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd> then choose "bone".

[image]

But as you can see, you may adjust the "barrel_joint" bone before doing all that :
[image]

Comment: Oh I see, this actually explains a lot about how bones work for me -- thank you so much. Do you have any idea about the barrel issue by any chance? http://puu.sh/pvKnN/178c635851.png

Comment: @MarcelDoe, which issue ?

Comment: Essentially whenever you rotate the revolver barrel, it's not supposed to fold into itself like the screenshot but rather do something kinda sort of like this -- http://puu.sh/pvMbs/2a8fabaa9f.png

Comment: Also one more question, if I'm adding the bone to an armature already existing it wont let me just rotate it 90 degrees here -- http://puu.sh/pvMvh/932b3ed082.png any ideas?

Comment: @MarcelDoe, I am sorry, but this is not a tutorial here. And the comments are not a discussion.

Comment: ok. I mean the first part is part of the original question in regards to the revolver barrel. plus it's a question in regards on how to get your solution to work well but yeah. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry, that is also not what I meant in regards to the edit.. Essentially, as the bone rotates I need the barrel to move forward.

http://puu.sh/pvMR5/b15d853f33.png This is what happens when I rotate the barrel right now.

Instead, as I rotate the barrel along the x-axis I need it to compensate so that instead it would be here -- http://puu.sh/pvMSQ/ce2e819cd4.png

basically the barrel needs to move in relation to the hinge point -- http://puu.sh/pvKra/a373efb1ac.png